# Angular 2 router navigate, goes to page and comes back

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 components:
ProductList
Product

When I click on a product in product list, it should go to product component.

ProductList, unselect of product
HTML:

```
 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" (click)="onSelect(item)">Learn more</a></p>
```

TS:

```
onSelect(product: IProduct) {
    this.router.navigate(['/product', product.productId]);
  }
```

It does go to product Component and consoles the id:

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) 
    {
        this._route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                let id = params['id'];
                console.log(id)
            });
     }
```

But then it navigates back the product list component why?\

Whereas if i do go from HTML that is use routerLink: It works...

```
[routerLink]="['/product',item.productId]"
```

Why?

Comment: Can you add the call to `onSelect` that you have in your template?

Comment: Please provide more information. What does your routes configuration look like?

Comment: you should also open your console and check for any errors. Sometimes, if there is errors in landing page, the app go back to previous working page (index page in general) but log the error

Comment: can you post your route config...

Comment: Remove `href="#"` from your `<a>`, it will mess with the routing...  Angular's `[routerLink]` will overwrite the `href` prop, whereas the `(click)` won't

Answer (score 3):

Remove the href="#" from your link.